# setTextSize for custom EditText and different screen sizes (small, normal, etc.)

Tags: android

I work on application which is supposed to be launched on different screens (small, normal, large, etc.). I have various `dimen.xml` files for various screens. Also I wrote a custom `EditText` widget. When I set text size from the xml the value is processed correctly. But when I use `setTextSize(resources.getDimension(R.dimen.something))`, the texts are too large. Isn't it possible to set the correct size from the Java file?

Comment: Are you using _dp_ as your unit in the xml file?

Comment: Set the text size via XML...then call `getTextSize` on your `EditText` and compare to the value you get from `resources.getDimension`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved using this code:

```
setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.textSize));
```

where `textSize` is stored in `dp`.

I know, that I can use

```
setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, resources.getDimension(R.dimen.textSize));
```

, but this one doesn't work.